# linux C++ XImage RGB <-> BGR?

Tags: c++, linux, rgb, xlib

I have a vector containing RGBA (actualy I don't care about the alpha channel) value from a picture, I want to draw this picture with xlib. So I have to use an XImage and to got one I need to use [XCreateImage](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XCreateImage.html).

XCreateImage requires "char *data" so first I need to convert my vector. I don't know if what I'm doing is efficient, but that works :

```
vector<unsigned char> picture;
cunsigned char *unsigneddata = &picture[0];
char *data;
data =  (char*)unsigneddata;
```

so now I can use "data" to draw my picture,

```
XImage *ximage = XCreateImage(display, visual /*errata : not window*/, 24, ZPixmap, 0, data, width, height, 32, 0);
XPutImage(dpy, *_w,gc,ximage,0,0,0,0,width,height);
```

my picture at screen has the red and the blue channels inverted. I don't know if I mess something or if it's correct and if I have to swap the channels. If I have to swap, there is another way than just doing a loop over the array to swap them ?

Comment: Does it work? `XCreateImage` requires a `Visual*` as the second parameter.

Comment: yes, a visual can be a window, as I said the problem is the inversion of red and blue channel, but still don't know if it's my fault or not

Comment: You should convert your data to the format understood by the visual. A visual info has `red_mask`, `green_mask` and `blue_mask` fields (see `XVisualInfo` struct) and you must set R, G and B of each pixel according to these masks. Yes this means going over each pixel and converting it. However, I don't know how to do that if your visual is a window, or what does it mean for the visual to be a window for that matter.

Comment: Im really sorry, I mess up between 'visual' and 'drawable' :
 visual IS NOT A WINDOW it's a visual I have
  Visual *myvisual;
  myvisual = DefaultVisual(dpy,0);
and 
XImage *ximage = XCreateImage(display, myvisual, 24, ZPixmap, 0, data, width, height, 32, 0);

maybe my problem doesn't come from XCreateImage but from XPutImage. I will take a look closer now of the the graphical context used in my XPutImage

Comment: I have just checked, no, the problem is really in `XCreateImage` and not in `XPutImage`. You have to set the bits according to the masks provided by the visual info. Setting the masks in XImage after the fact doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you know what? I'm tired of dat shit!
I just swap the values...

```
  // invert red and blue, xlib ams dumb, it using BGR instead of RGB...
  unsigned char red, blue;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<image.size();i+=4){
   red  = image[i+2];
   blue = image[i];
   image[i]   = red;
   image[i+2] = blue;
  }
```

thank you for your comments n.m.