# XLib Window background has colours inverted

Tags: colors, background, window, png, xlib

I'm almost there with my little "*window background from PNG image*" project in Linux. I use pure **X11** API and the minimal [LodePNG](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://lodev.org/lodepng/&ei=WqjqUou1E8iShQeTzYGwDQ&usg=AFQjCNFUDfbZXHKJ_VZKCNSyg7PfQP0LfA&sig2=cT8Y4Aqv0AQ9g04jV5fTVw) to load the image. The problem is that the background is the negative of the original PNG image and I don't know what could be the problem.

This is basically the code that loads the image then creates the pixmap and applies the background to the window:

```
// required headers
// global variables
Display *display;
Window window;
int window_width = 600;
int window_height = 400;

// main entry point

// load the image with lodePNG (I didn't modify its code)
vector<unsigned char> image;
unsigned width, height;

//decode
unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, "bg.png");
if(!error)
{
    // And here is where I apply the image to the background
    Screen* screen = NULL;
    screen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(display);

    // Creating the pixmap
    Pixmap pixmap = XCreatePixmap(
        display, 
        XDefaultRootWindow(display), 
        width, 
        height, 
        DefaultDepth(display, 0)
    );

    // Creating the graphic context
    XGCValues gr_values;
    gr_values.function = GXcopy;
    gr_values.background = WhitePixelOfScreen(display);

    // Creating the image from the decoded PNG image
    XImage *ximage = XCreateImage(
        display, 
        CopyFromParent, 
        DisplayPlanes(display, 0), 
        ZPixmap, 
        0, 
        (char*)&image, 
        width, 
        height, 
        32, 
        4 * width
    );

    // Place the image into the pixmap
    XPutImage(
        display, 
        pixmap, 
        gr_context, 
        ximage, 
        0, 0, 
        0, 0, 
        window_width, 
        window_height
    );

    // Set the window background
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(display, window, pixmap);

    // Free up used resources
    XFreePixmap(display, pixmap);
    XFreeGC(display, gr_context);
}
```

The image is decoded (and there's the possibility to be badly decoded) then it is applied to the background but, as I said, the image colors are inversed and I don't know why.

**MORE INFO**

After decoding I encoded the same image into a PNG file which is identical to the decoded one, so it looks like the problem is not related to LodePNG but to the way I play with XLib in order to place it on the window.

**EVEN MORE INFO**
Now I compared the inverted image with the original one and found out that somewhere in my code the RGB is converted to BGR. If one pixel on the original image is *95, 102, 119* on the inverted one it is *119, 102, 95*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017432/linux-c-ximage-rgb-bgr). I am not sure if is the best way but the simpler for sure.